# php-resque : Retry failed jobs

Tags: laravel, redis, php-resque

I have already setup php-resque on Laravel. Everything works great except failed jobs.

I can't see any option to requeue (retry) jobs that marked as failed.

I see that in redis db there is a queue named "failed" but how i can re-push each failed_job back to the parent queue?

I've searched everywhere (php-resque documentation, google etc..) but found nothing for php-resque. Only ready-made solution for ruby version...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is plugin for php-resque: https://github.com/JaapRood/php-resque-retry